# CSS3 animation project structure

Tags: html, css

I am working on a CSS/HTML only application, no JavaScript, no 3rd party frameworks or plugins.
The application has a lot of CSS3 animations.
What is the best way to structure my css files and classes so I don't repeat my codes again and again?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [Sass pre-processor](http://sass-lang.com/) to write your CSS (especially the SCSS version) which will ensure that your final output is DRY as possible with minimum or no redundancies.

I would propose the following directory structure, to organise your Sass/SCSS files,

```
styles/
|
|-- partials/
|   |-- _bounce.scss
|   |-- _fade.scss
|   |-- _flip.scss
|   |-- _rotate.scss
|   |-- _wobble.scss
|
`-- animations.scss          # Primary Sass file
```

The `animations.scss` file will be your primary SCSS file that will import all the partials. Inside the `partials` directory, you can maintain a separate SCSS file for each type of animation.

This will massively help you organise your project and the solution is scalable. For example, take a look at how this repository is designed for [animate.scss](https://github.com/hmps/animate.scss).

Answer (score 1):

I would create an `animations.css` which contains all the animations and transitions. You should address them by a class – which then could get re-used.

All of what Pankaj Parashar has answered holds true for plain CSS also. [Import the single CSS files using `@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import). The following is an example for a spinner (e.g. AJAX load icon). Any element with the class `.spin` would turn around over and ver again. But in contrast to using SCSS or LESS mixins you have to create all vendor-prefixed  variants on your own

animations.css:

```
@keyframes spin {
    0%   { transform:rotate(0deg) }
    100% { transform:rotate(359deg) }
}

.spin {
    animation:spin 2s infinite linear
}
```

style.css:

```
@import 'animations.css'
/* further rules */
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. I intentionally did not recommend using `@import` statements in CSS due to performance overhead, heavily documented here - http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Comment: Also, OP aims to avoid repeated code which would be very difficult to achieve with just CSS.

Comment: @PankajParashar That last point is a question of the definition. I've seen to many bad examples in SCSS/LESS that have their code organized in mixins, but do use a mixin call rather than [extends](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) and so creating a hell of bloated CSS code with large chunks of repeated code in the final output. To create good-performance CSS using a preprocessor you should know CSS very well in the first place,

Comment: Agree, you cannot use CSS pre-processor without knowing CSS. Additionally, writing mixins/extends is a matter of poor coding practise, however, using `@imports` is a big NO-NO and definitely not recommended.